# Realm Count incorrect/inconsistant off Main Thread

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

I'm seeing a very weird problem with getting the count from a query not running on the main thread. I have a UI that uses the `RecyclerView` adapter for Realm, and it works just dandy.

I have a method that counts the number of records before a query so it can set a starting point, for some reason it will return the previous count was before the last transaction. Here is a somewhat shortened version with the output of the log:

```
D/SearchController: Query Count (Main Thread): 50
D/SearchController: Query Count (Rx Thread): 50
D/SearchController: Query Count (Main Thread): 100
D/SearchController: Query Count (Rx Thread): 50

public Single<Update> searchWithCriteriaForMore(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        Realm realmI = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Timber.d("Query Count (Main Thread): %d", realmI.where(Ad.class).equalTo("searchId", searchCriteria.id()).count());
        realmI.close();
        return Single.defer(() -> {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            Timber.d("Query Count (Rx Thread): %d", realm.where(Ad.class).equalTo("searchId", searchCriteria.id()).count());
            realm.close();
// Stuff to add records on Rx Thread
        });
    }
```

The call looks like this:

```
SearchController.instance().searchWithCriteriaForMore(searchCriteria)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new SingleSubscriber<SearchController.Update>() {
        ...
     }
```

Thoughts anyone? I've been trying to nail this down for a few weeks, thought it was something I was doing, but if I do the count on the main thread and pass it in, it works fine.

I'm running RxJava 1.2.7, RxAndroid 1.2.1, and Realm 3.3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm using minSdk 16, so can't use the resource idea, but I did put the counting in a transaction and now it is getting the correct counts. This shouldn't be necessary, but guess that's life.

Comment: Nah, actually you can remove the transaction and replace it with `realm.refresh()` after `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` if you're using Realm 3.2+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels that you have a Realm instance on RxThread somewhere which is not closed before. Since RxThread doesn't have a looper, the realm instance cannot be auto-updated. So it was locked at the version when it was created.

Realm is using ref counter internally, the `getDefaultInstance()` will just return the same instance you opened on the RxThread before.

The solution:
1. Find out which Realm instance was retrieved on the RxThread and close it properly. So the next time `getDefaultInstance()` will return a new Realm instance at the latest version data.
2. If it is intended to have a Realm instance on the RxThread, you can call `realm.refresh()` to manually move it to the latest data version.